# Custom Fragment cannot be cast to other custom Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to simply replace one custom fragment by another one. The first custom fragment is called `MenuFragment` and extends `ListFragment`. When the activity is created (onCreate) I insert it in a layout (called `layout_container`) I've defined in XML :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
MenuFragment menufragment = new MenuFragment(); 
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layout_container, menufragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here, I've got no problem.

Then I want to replace it with the second fragment called `AlbumsFragment` (which also extends `ListFragment`) when the user clicks on something. In my onClick event I put :

```
AlbumsFragment albumsfragment = new AlbumsFragment(); 
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.layout_container, albumsfragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Here the new fragment is well displayed and replaces the menufragment but at the same time the app crashes and the LogCat says :

```
 E/AndroidRuntime(25105): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.music.musicapp.AlbumsFragment cannot be cast to com.music.musicapp.MenuFragment
```

I'm only using and targeting Api level 15 and so I don't use the Android Support Package.

**EDIT :**
Here is my Album fragment code, very simple, it is just a list with two items "Album1" and "Album2". I can see these two items after the click is performed, but immediatly the app crashes.

```
package com.music.musicapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class AlbumsFragment extends ListFragment {

            // declare the array list
             ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

             @Override
                public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


                // Fill up Array 
                    array.add("album1");
                    array.add("album2");

                    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));


                 }   

}
```

Comment: I don't see a cast in the code you posted anywhere... is that somewhere else in your code?  If the fragment displays, it's an issue in your code for the fragment.  Post your AlbumsFragment code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved,

I had another method which needed the `MenuFragment` and thus, when this fragment was replaced by `AlbumsFragment`, this method was making the app crash because it refered to a no more existent fragment.

So the problem was not in the code posted, sorry. It is important to consider the impact of replacing a fragment, and be careful when  referring to it (check if it is still on the UI or if it has been already sent to the back stack, etc...).

Thanks for your answers and sorry for not having seen that my problem wasn't there (but when the project's getting complex, is hard to always see from where the problem comes :/).